# Spring integration: transform http message to soap message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http, spring-integration-ws

I'm writing an application to support a [protocol](https://cwmp-data-models.broadband-forum.org/) that in the same HTTP endpoint mixes SOAP messages (a POST with SOAP XML) with empty messages (a POST without body), which are not empty SOAP messages.

I tried to receive the empty messages using `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` but I get 400 (bad request), which is reasonable because an empty body is not a valid SOAP message.

My idea (maybe is not the best) is to use `Http.inboundGateway` to receive all HTTP requests and then route the messages to `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` if they are not empty, but I'm having a problem.

If I use `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` directly I am able to receive messages using this `SoapMessageService`:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SOAP_MESSAGE_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME)
  public SoapMessage receive(SoapMessage soapMessage) {
    System.out.println(soapMessage);
    return soapMessage;
  }
```

But when I put in the flow the `Http.inboundGateway` before the `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway`, that service will not work anymore because:

`EL1004E: Method call: Method receive(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type com.example.services.SoapMessageService`

This (using `String` instead of `SoapMessage`) works fine:

```
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SOAP_MESSAGE_SERVICE_CHANNEL_NAME)
  public String receive(String soapMessage) {
    System.out.println(soapMessage);
    return soapMessage;
  }
```

But definitely I don't want to perform the conversion from String to SoapMessage by myself, specially when I know that the framework can resolve it, like when I receive the messages directly in `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` and I process them as `SoapMessage`.

So I would like to know how can I use Spring Integration in the best possible way to receive the HTTP messages as `SoapMessage` in a service activator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Http.inboundGateway()` has this option:

```
/**
 * Set the message body converters to use.
 * These converters are used to convert from and to HTTP requests and responses.
 * @param messageConverters The message converters.
 * @return the current Spec.
 */
public S messageConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>... messageConverters) {
```

So, essentially you can write an `HttpMessageConverter` to create a `SoapMessage` from the HTTP request:

```
public class SoapMessageHttpConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<SoapMessage> {
    
    private final SoapMessageFactory soapMessageFactory;

    SoapMessageHttpConverter(SoapMessageFactory soapMessageFactory) {
        this.soapMessageFactory = soapMessageFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected SoapMessage readInternal(Class<? extends SoapMessage> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, IOException {
        
        return soapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(inputMessage.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(SoapMessage soapMessage, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) 
            throws HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
}
```